# Binding shapes together in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm attempting to bind some shapes together so when I drag the circle, the line will follow it as well. The circle moves when I drag it, but the line doesn't follow. I'm trying to use .bind but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Here are some of the relevant methods.

```
private Line connect(Line line, Circle startNode, Circle endNode) {
        line.startXProperty().bind(startNode.centerXProperty());
        line.startYProperty().bind(startNode.centerYProperty());
        line.endXProperty().bind(endNode.centerXProperty());
        line.endYProperty().bind(endNode.centerYProperty());

    return line;
}    

private void pointsToShapes() {
    connect(leftArm, neckNode, leftHandNode);

    leftHandNode.setCenterX(leftHand.x);
    leftHandNode.setCenterY(leftHand.y);

    neckNode.setCenterX(shoulder.x);
    neckNode.setCenterY(shoulder.y);

}
    leftHandNode.setOnMousePressed(mp);

    leftHandNode.setOnMouseDragged(md);     

    //mouse pressed
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> mp = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
       public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        System.out.println("pressed");
        sceneX = t.getSceneX();
        sceneY = t.getSceneY();
        translateX = ((Circle)(t.getSource())).getTranslateX();
        translateY = ((Circle)(t.getSource())).getTranslateY();
        }
    };

   //mouse dragged 
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> md = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            System.out.println("dragged");
            double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - sceneX;
            double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - sceneY;
            double newTranslateX = translateX + offsetX;
            double newTranslateY = translateY + offsetY;

            ((Circle)(t.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
            ((Circle)(t.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Setting `translateX` and `translateY` doesn't result in a modification of `centerX` and `centerY`. Since the property you bind to remains unchanged, the bound properies also remain unchanged...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @fabian mentioned, you need to consider translate properties while binding to line properties.

```
private Line connect(Line line, Circle startNode, Circle endNode) {
        line.startXProperty().bind(startNode.centerXProperty().add(startNode.translateXProperty()));
        line.startYProperty().bind(startNode.centerYProperty().add(startNode.translateYProperty()));
        line.endXProperty().bind(endNode.centerXProperty().add(endNode.translateXProperty()));
        line.endYProperty().bind(endNode.centerYProperty().add(endNode.translateYProperty()));

    return line;
}
```